# Replace a value in a column if that value appears only once

Tags: python

I have a dataframe, I want to replace the values in one column by "other" if the value count of that value in that column is exactly 1

```
i        Food_group
0          Flake
1          Flake
2          Flake
3         Almond
4          Drink
5          Drink
6          Flake
```

I have tried,

```
data["food_group"] = data.food_group.apply(lambda x: "other" if x.value_counts()==1 else x)
```

I got error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier if you store the value count separately to avoid redoing it inside the apply loop. You can do it like this:

```
food_count = data["food_group"].value_counts()
data["food_group"] = data["food_group"].apply(lambda x: "other" if food_count[x]==1 else x)
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? it does not work

Comment: Test it now. :) Tried on another dataset and forgot to change back to "food_group"

Comment: Tested it on your data now, so it should work.